# FastAPI: Cross Requests freeze my microservices when they are too frequent

Tags: python-3.x, rest, asynchronous, fastapi

I discover FastAPI for the first time with which I try to discuss 2 services.

When a service asks "how are you?" the other service replies "Good!", and vice versa. The same requests are therefore made in both directions, they are crossed.... And this is repeated after a certain delay.

Here is my code for a service (it's the same code for the 2 services).
It works well, except when the delay is too short!

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import requests
import uvicorn
import asyncio


app = FastAPI()


def get(url, headers, json_data=False):
    if json_data:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json=json_data)
    else:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r


@app.get("/")
async def how_are_you():
    message = f"{service_name}: Good!"
    print(message)
    return message


async def toc_toc(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    url = f"http://{remote_host}:{remote_port}/"
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
    }
    count = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(waiting)
        print(f"{count}\t{service_name}: {message}!")
        get(url, headers)
        count += 1


async def run_webserver():
    config = uvicorn.Config(app, host=host, port=port)
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    await server.serve()


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        toc_toc("How are you"),
        run_webserver()
    )
```

Here are the input variables
of my first serve:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    waiting = 0.1
    service_name = "service_1"
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 82
    remote_host = "0.0.0.0"
    remote_port = 83
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = main()
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

And those of my second service:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    waiting = 0.1
    service_name = "service_2"
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 83
    remote_host = "0.0.0.0"
    remote_port = 82
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = main()
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

If I set this delay "waiting" to 1 second (between 2 requests "how are you?"), I have no problem. Everything works perfectly for minutes at least.
On the other hand, if I reduce this variable to 0.1 seconds (or even lower), the services send each other requests and respond to each other a hundred times and then the applications seem to freeze.
So I don't have any error message that could help me to debug.
I need to be able to lower this delay to 0.001 seconds to simulate a production load peak that my services will have to be able to support.

I have the impression that the problem comes from the fact that the requests are crossed between my 2 services. Because in the case where only one service can send requests to the other (by commenting out the `get(url, headers)` line for service 2), it works very well even with a delay of 0.001 seconds.

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

PS: I run my services directly on my Mac M1 but also on my local Kubernets cluster, and I have the same result.

Comment: I think uvicorn defaults to a single worker, try setting it to two or higher (depending on available cpus). Perhaps you're running out of resources deadlocking the application.

Comment: Hi @HeddevanderHeide, I just tested, and unfortunately I get the same result with a number of workers set to 1, 2, 3, or 4. Thank you anyway for this idea.

Comment: which waiting time did you use to test this? I think 0.001 with a low number of workers is going to get problematic very fast, the response time is going to be longer than that so the number of requests will probably outgrow capacity very soon

Comment: I used a waiting time of 0.1 seconds.
I just retested with 0.1 seconds but putting 10, 20 then 100 workers but I get the same result

Comment: How exactly do you set the worker setting? Are you running virtualised, have you checked network consumption? I've tested your script and it hangs on one worker, but seems to do better with two (only tested 0.1)